# Travelling wave and phase velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

[image]

[image]

[image]

I know it sounds easy for most of you all but why is b) not a travelling wave because from what I know b) can be differentiated twice so shouldn't it be a travelling wave?

For d) Can I find the phase velocity using the equation $$\psi(x,t) = f(kx-\omega t)$$
So for d) it is

$$A\cos^2 (-2\pi x-(-2\pi t)) $$

and from the formula $v=\omega/k$ where w is angular frequency and $k$ is the wave number, $v= -2\pi/-2\pi =$ 1 m/s? Is my method correct?

Comment: Does the equation for $\psi(x,t)$ satisfy the equation $\dfrac{\partial ^2\psi}{\partial x^2} = \dfrac{1}{c^2} \dfrac{\partial ^2\psi}{\partial t^2}\,\,$ or the equivalent with $z$ as the position variable.?

Comment: hi @Farcher can I say b) satisfy because it can be differentiated twice but it does not satisfy travelling wave(which is what the question is asking for) because v=w/k does not work for b)??

Comment: Being able to differential twice has not a lot to do with it. You have to make sure that if you differentiate $\psi$ twice with respect to $z$ and then you differentiate $\psi$ twice with respect to $t$ the wave equation is satisfied for all values of $z$ and $t$ which it is not whereas the other equation for $\psi$ does satisfy the wave equation..

Comment: In (d) the units seem wrong.  How can I subtract a length from a time?  Isn't that apples and oranges?   In order to be able to do that subtraction,  both $x$ and $t$ must be dimensionless.  That means that the units of space and time have been set up in advance to be multiples of some characteristic length and time.  This adds a technical twist to the question.  But the resolution is this:  since $x$ and $t$ are dimensionless, the velocity of that wave is $v=1$, no units.  That means $1$ characteristic length per characteristic time.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'll try a definition of a wave. In one dimension (e.g., with coordinate z), any solution of (a system of) a linear partial differential equation of the form $$\psi(z, t)=\psi_0 \exp (ikz-i\omega t) \tag 1$$ where $\psi_0$ is the (complex) amplitude, $k$ is the wave vector, and $\omega$ is the angular frequency, can be considered to be a "wave" with phase velocity $$v_{ph}=\frac {\omega }{k}$$ and group velocity $$v_{gr}=\frac{\partial \omega}{\partial k}$$ Any linear superposition of such sinusoid waves is again a wave.  The functional relation between the frequency $\omega$ and the wave vector $k$, $$D(\omega, k)=0$$ is called the dispersion relation, where $\omega $ and $k$ can be complex. It follows from the partial differential equations defining the wave propagation. Solutions (1) of the proper wave equation have the simple linear dispersion relation $$\omega =v_{ph} k$$ with a constant phase velocity, which is equal to the group velocity $$v_{ph}=v_{gr}$$ More complex systems, like a medium with damping, have more complicated (non-linear) dispersion relations so that both phase and group velocities can become frequency (or wave length) dependent. Usually, solutions as eq. (1) are considered propagting wave in frequency and wave vector ranges where both $\omega$ and $k$ have real parts, so that real phase and group velocities ($v_{gr} \neq 0$) can be defined, which usually signifies the propagation of a signal/energy.

The function (b) of the question seems not to be expressible as a linear combination of $t$ an $z$. It thus cannot be regarded to represent a propagating wave. Function (d) should be a propagating wave.

Anybody who thinks that this is a still wanting description of a traveling wave is asked to improve it or provide a better definition.

Comment: I wish that those luminaries, who downvote this, have also the guts to give an explanation for that, or provide a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

(b) is not a travelling wave because it is not of the form
$$f(x-vt)+g(x+vt)$$
It does not satisfy the wave equation.

(d) is correct.

Comment: hi @velut luna, thanks for commenting but can I say it is a wave but it is not a travelling wave because it does not satisfy v=w/k ??

Comment: What is your definition of wave？

Comment: hi @velut luna from what I know something is a wave when its function can be differentiated twice like psy(x,t) = 2(x^2)( t^2) is a wave but is not a travelling wave?

Comment: I can't find a rigorous definition of wave on wikipedia. So may be you can say so. For me, wave is what satisfies the wave equation.

Comment: @velutluna Then any damped wave is not a "wave"?

Comment: @freecharly So what is your definition?

Comment: @velutluna I have tried to give a definition. See below.

Comment: The language has to be taken in context.  "Wave" means solution of wave equation.  A damped wave is a damped wave, not a wave.  But one might use a short-hand language and refer to a damped wave as a wave.  Context and understanding.

Comment: @garyp Then, in your opinion, a light wave attenuated due to absorption in a medium is not a wave? And neither an amplified wave in a travelling wave tube?

Comment: I'm making a semantic point.  The usual definition of a wave is that it solves the wave equation.   There are other propagating disturbances that look a whole lot like a wave, but do not satisfy the wave equation.  In the context of a question like that of the OP, they would not be waves.   But everyone would *call* them waves.  Context, context, and context.

Comment: @garyp I understand your point. But I think that it is common usage also to designate damped waves as waves. Even the solutions of the Schrödinger equation  are called waves. And solutions of the telegrapher's equation of lossy transmission lines are called waves, and solution of Maxwell's equations in wave guides are called waves.